# Unnecessary data returned by express.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I just made simple REST API using Express.js but there is an unnecessary data being returned by express.

Here's the response data:

```
{
    "code": 200,
    "status": "success",
    "message": "Success",
    "device_code": "2F1E6DB930",
    "data": [
        {
            "_id": "5d84801cd3906f1e5cbec0c4"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d848032d3906f1e5cbec0c6"
        },
        {
            "_id": "5d8480bbd3906f1e5cbec0ca"
        }
    ]
}
```

The "data" object is not needed because I didn't return it on my code

```
exports.register = async (req, res) => {
  if (utils.checkBody(req.body, utils.authBody)) {
    let User = services.db.collection('users')

    let deviceCode = Math.random().toString(16).substr(2, 10).toUpperCase()

    await User.insertOne({
      username: req.body.username,
      password: md5(req.body.password + process.env.SECRET_KEY),
      kode_device: deviceCode
    })

    response = Object.assign(utils.requestResponse.success, { device_code: deviceCode })
  } else {
    response = utils.requestResponse.incomplete_body
  }

  res.status(response.code).json(response)
}

// request response success

const requestResponse = {
  success: {
    code: 200,
    status: 'success',
    message: 'Success'
  }
}
```

The only "data" object I returned to is in another endpoint (let's say 'show data') and here's the code

```
exports.show = async (req, res) => {
  if (req.params.device_code) {
    let General = services.db.collection(req.params.device_code)
    let query = undefined

    if (req.query.last_id === undefined || req.query.last_id === '') {
      query = {}
    } else {
      query = { _id: { '$gt':  ObjectId(req.query.last_id) } }
    }

    let data = await General.find(query).limit(10).toArray()

    response = Object.assign(utils.requestResponse.success, { data: data })
  } else {
    response = utils.requestResponse.incomplete_body
  }

  res.status(response.code).json(response)
}
```

I made an script to cluster the app server code and run through `nodemon`

```
require('dotenv').config()
const cluster = require('cluster')
const AppServer = require('./app')

if (cluster.isMaster) {
  let cpuCount = require('os').cpus().length

  for (let i = 0; i < cpuCount; i += 1) {
    cluster.fork()
  }
} else {
  console.log(`Server is running on ${process.env.PORT}`)
  AppServer.listen(process.env.PORT)
}
cluster.on('exit', (worker) => {
  console.log('server',`Worker %d die ${worker.id}`);
  cluster.fork();
})
```

Is there any solution? Thank you.

Comment: Sooo, how is my answer going? We waste free time here for you. At least give a bit of feedback... :-(

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to see the contents of `utils.requestResponse.success` before sending it?

As a tip: There's a way to debug this. Put a breakpoint when the request start, and go step by step until you see that there's a `data` property in your response object, analyzing all the variables involved in this part of the code. You will notice that the problem is your `utils.requestResponse.success` object.

This way you will notice that `Object.assign` will modify the object passed as the first argument, so when the `show` endpoint is called, you notice that `utils.requestResponse.success` is modified and a `data` property is added to it. Is the same as doing:

```
utils.requestResponse.success.data = data;
```

You must pass an empty object `{}` as the first argument, `utils.requestResponse.success` as the second and `{data: data}` as the third. This way the object modified is the first empty object just created.